# No auto refresh for chef vaults during knife bootstrap

Tags: chef-infra, knife

I have created a chef vault and item with a specific search query associated with it.

On doing knife bootstrap, chef vault is not getting refreshed with the newly created chef node.How can I achieve this?

Do I have to explicitly run knife vault refresh command every time? I am using chef 12. I am passing --bootstrap-vault-item Vault:Item in knife bootstrap command.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Updating the vault during bootstrapping is still an unsolved problem for chef-vault and listed on the [TODO list](https://github.com/Nordstrom/chef-vault/blob/8fda53e6570dbfe75279344091b8ce2adb081598/Changelog.md#v300).

Answer (score 0):

I use terraform and chef provider to achieve this.
within tf file You have to provide list of vaults needed to be refreshed during bootstrap i.e:

```
resource "null_resource" "some_machine_chef_bootstrap" {
....
    vault_json = <<-EOF
    {
      "vault1": "item1"
      "vault2": [
        "item1",
        "item2",
        "item3"
      ]
    }
    EOF
....
```